# rcov code coverage issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rcov

I am using rcov (0.9.11), ruby 1.8.7, Rails 3.1, spec 2.7. The coverage report shows some of the code as having 0% coverage but I have test coverage for it. When I modify the code with 0% coverage, I get failing tests.

I also found an open bug on Github related to this. Does anyone know of any workaround for this issue? If what alternative tool would you recommend? TIA.